# sql query to sum values in the two least columns out of five columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

a database table named '`StudentResults`' stores results of students' subject tests. and those tests are graded based on performance. so there are grades for maths score, french score, english score, science score and Agric score. i want to create a query that will check and sum up the two least results from the entire five different results.
 eg. john maths = 40 french = 50 english= 60 science =30 agric = 70. the two least results are 30 and 40 out of the total five subject tests. how do i write a query to sum them up. table example below:

> | Name  | Maths | French | English | Science |  Agric  |
>   Two_Least | 
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>  | james |   30.0  
>   |    50.0  |   70.0 
>   |      10.0    |   70.0  |    40.0       
>   | 
>  | joshie |   10.0  
>   |    30.0  |   40.0 
>   |      10.0    |   70.0  |    20.0       
>   | 
> | janete |   20.0  
>   |    60.0  |   70.0 
>   |      80.0    |   90.0  |    80.0        |

james two least are maths = 30 science = 10. Two_Least = 40
joshie two least are maths = 10 science =  10. Two_Leats = 20
janete two least are maths = 20 French = 60. Two_Least = 80
please how do i write an sql query to solve this. thank you all very much.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sqlite please @jarlh

Comment: I would look at normalizing your database. No real good way to do this in SQLite without a bunch of CASE statements

Comment: i plan on sharing the file through network folders so that it could be accessed by many computers. am not too good in sockets and server sockets @kbball. thats why i chose sqlite for this boss. i will appreciate your answers too very much boss.

Comment: SQLite is not the issue.... It's that you would ideally have name, subject, score as your row structure - hence all the unions you are seeing below

Answer (score 2):

I you are using `SQL Server` or `Oracle 12c` you could use:

```
SELECT t.*, s.two_least
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(val)
             FROM (
               SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z.val) AS rn, z.val
               FROM (
                 SELECT t.Maths UNION ALL       --FROM dual
                 SELECT t.French UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.English UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.Science UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.Agric
                 ) z(val)
              ) v
              WHERE rn IN (1,2)
           ) s(two_least);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HVUBA61431)**

---

`SQLite` version (correlation should be done through some kind of `id`):

```
SELECT *, MIN(Maths, French, English, Science, Agric) + 
( SELECT  Maths AS s FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL 
  SELECT  French     FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  English    FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  Science    FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  Agric      FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name
  ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1
) AS result
FROM t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=cd69cfe490510d5c949c191618157c5f)**

**Correct way: Normalize your schema.**

---

EDIT:

MySQL supports LEAST function:

```
SELECT *, LEAST(Maths, French, English, Science, Agric) + 
( SELECT  Maths AS s FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL 
  SELECT  French     FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  English    FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  Science    FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name UNION ALL
  SELECT  Agric      FROM t t2 WHERE t.Name = t2.Name
  ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1
) AS result
FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a8377f61fcdfeddf0a9f77c06130c48)**

Comment: OP just said sqlite.

Comment: @jarlh In original question there was only SQL tag. Anyway it is easy to adapt.

Comment: @lad2025 will your answer work with sqlite? sorry for not including the sqlite tag. my appologies.

Comment: @jarlh SQLite is more limited than I thought :/

Comment: thank you very @lad2025. it worked. so 'result column' is a virtual column. is there a way to update it into a real column please.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thank you for your query answers. the sqlite worked perfectly. unfortunately i'm using mysql now and the query example for sql server doesnt work for mysql. please is there a way i can get it to work with mysql please

Comment: @RodneyNart Insead of `MIN` function use `LEAST`. [Demo MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a8377f61fcdfeddf0a9f77c06130c48)

Comment: thank you @LukaszSzozda , it worked perfeclty. am most gratefull. You really good and a great teacher.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda hello after 3years. i posted an app with the sql query example but unfortunately their database doesnt support utf8_general_ci collation so the best i could use was **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** and that throws error to the mysql query. this is an example below:

Comment: `String sql="update jhs2 set Agregate=(SELECT French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G, LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G) +" + 
" (SELECT French_G AS s FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL " +
" SELECT Rme_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT Ict_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT GhLang_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT BasicDesign_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID" +
" ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1) AS result FROM jhs2 WHERE ID = jhs2.ID)";`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda the error states : `Operand should contain 1 column(s)error in jhs2` how do i update the select query into a real column for that database collation type. thank you.

Comment: @RodneyNart I am not sure  I get the issue, but if you want to change collation on the fly use [COLLATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i want to update 'Agregate column' for each record with the above sql syntax query. but with the above query, i get an error stating `Operand should contain 1 column(s)error in jhs2(table)`. it works well with sqlite but not with mysql. kindly check the query code and advice appropriately how it should be written please. thank you

Comment: please advice how this query should be written well. `String sql="update jhs2 set Agregate=(SELECT French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G, LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G) +" +  " (SELECT French_G AS s FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL " + " SELECT Rme_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" + " SELECT Ict_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" + " SELECT GhLang_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" + " SELECT BasicDesign_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID" + " ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1) AS result FROM jhs2 WHERE ID = jhs2.ID)";`

Comment: @RodneyNart In case of  `UPDATE jhs2 set aggregate = (SELECT  French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G, LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G)` - the issue is you are returning multiple columns from subquery and try to assign to aggregate.  Use the only one you want to assign or combine them somehow(I would remove `French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G,` from column list and left only `LEAST(....) + ...`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i did that & wrote it this way: `update jhs2 set Agregate=(SELECT LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G) +" + 
" (SELECT French_G AS s FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL " +
" SELECT Rme_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT Ict_G  FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT GhLang_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
" SELECT BasicDesign_G FROM jhs2 t2 WHERE jhs2.ID = t2.ID ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1) AS result) WHERE ID = jhs2.ID` but error says `You can't specify target table 'jhs2' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @RodneyNart Without reporducible code I am unable to do more. Feel free to create a demo that shows this exact error using: https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @LukaszSzozda this is the link please. i am grateful. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4e0696a4b80c07263d45f3114a4e704

Comment: @RodneyNart https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5e8236ca602f3fcd52e6a261ddc39fe

Comment: @LukaszSzozda please after running a select statement of the table, only the first record is correct. the remaining 3 rows are not correct please. eg row two: least 2 are 10 and 5 = 15(_not_25_) row three: least 2 are 10 and 5 = 15(_not_22_) and row four: least 2 are 13 and 5 = 18 (_not_23_). kindly check please.thank you a lot. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82707db30dfebb7eabf3dc68f066dd63

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i did a quick change of values for the first row and after running the query, i realized the first row too is not matching up big boss, i think its summing values but not the least two of each row. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37a11d0a3b725190036cdcde0dd6a5a5

Comment: @RodneyNart Everything is fine. Please use correct data types! Note should be int/numeric not text. **[Working DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ac6dd23a637804c148cbe402868e6c4)**

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thank you very much. you are really a life saver. its an honor to meet you. is there any tutorials you selling boss. i will very much want to enroll and be your student

Answer (score 2):

If this were my choice - I'd have a seperate table, ie - Grades (StudentId, Class, Grade) is table 2, and Students (StudentId, Name) - it would make querying things much easier.

Lad's solution will work for you, but restructuring the table seems wise.

Comment: thanks for your query code @lad2025. will try it out boss. may you stay blessed.

Answer (score 1):

i found a way for updating it into a real column. its..

```
String sql = "update t set Agregate=(SELECT MIN(Maths,French,English,Science,Agric) + " +
"( SELECT  Maths AS s FROM t t2 WHERE t.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL " +
"  SELECT  French FROM t t2 WHERE t.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  English FROM t t2 WHERE t.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  Science FROM t t2 WHERE t.ID = t2.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  Agric FROM t t2 WHERE t.ID = t2.ID" +
"  ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1" +
") AS result WHERE ID = t.ID
```

many thanks my bosses. i highly appreciate the efforts from every one. thanks @lad2025.